How to get the accurate total count of users in cognito user pool for large data?
Cognito user pool total users accurate count
In my user pool i have a 40k users, so i try to get the count of the user pool by using the describeuserpool sdk but its show's only limited data. any other way to get the count of user pool.
Thank you
